# React map leaflet add/remove circleMarker onClick

Tags: jquery, reactjs, leaflet

I have a React leaflet map, and I have a button. I add some circleMarkers in the map when I clicked the button, after make filter() and forEach().
And I want to delete or hidden the circleMarkers when I will click again, as a toggle. I have two css className : visible and hidden
But I want to change the circleMarkers from visible to hidden all at the same click. Now I have to click several times to remove all the circleMarkers, because the clikc only remove one circleMarker

COMPONENT MAP

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import './map.css'

function Map() {

    const apartments = [
        { roomType: 'shared room', geometry: [41.402610, 2.204270] },
        { roomType: 'shared room', geometry: [41.411300, 2.217630] },
        { roomType: 'private room', geometry: [41.410220, 2.212520] },
        { roomType: 'apartament sencer', geometry: [41.410630, 2.216970] },
        { roomType: 'private room', geometry: [41.409190, 2.209030] },
    ]

    let map = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        let url = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}'
        const access = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9zZXQyMSIsImEiOiJjazF1bGZlcHowYjVlM2RwYW9ia2pwaWtlIn0.9n-6tKArfdSfd15Do6YxLA'
        map.current = L.map("map");
        const defaultCenter = [41.383, 2.173];
        const defaultZoom = 13.10;

        let layer = L.tileLayer(url, {
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            accessToken: access,
        });

        map.current.setView(defaultCenter, defaultZoom);
        layer.addTo(map.current);
       }, [map])

    const handleOnclik = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let color = (e.target.name)

        if (color === 'pink') {
            let pink = document.querySelector('.visible')
            if (!pink) {

                let circle
                var result = apartments.filter(item => {
                    if (item.roomType === 'private room' || item.roomType === 'shared room') { return item.geometry }
                })

                result.forEach(({ geometry }) => {
                    circle = new L.CircleMarker(geometry, {
                        radius: 5,
                        fillColor: "pink",
                        width: 0.5,
                        stroke: "black",
                        color: '#FF1493',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5,
                        id: 'pink',
                        className: 'visible'
                    }).addTo(map.current);
                });
            } else {
                pink.classList.remove('visible')
                pink.classList.add('hidden')
            }
        }
    }

    return (<>
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                <div id="map" className="normalscreen"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="basemaps-wrapper" className="leaflet-bar">
                <select id="basemaps">
                    <option>Visualització</option>
                    <option value="mapbox.streets">Streets</option>
                    <option value="mapbox.satellite">Satellite</option>
                    <option value="mapbox.outdoors">Outdoors</option>
                    <option value="mapbox.dark">Dark</option>
                    <option value="mapbox.light">Light</option>
                    <option value="mapbox.DarkGray">Dark Gray</option>
                </select>
                <button onClick={onChangeFullScreen}>Full Screen</button>
                <div>
                    <img onClick={handleOnclik} name="pink" src="images/pink.svg" alt="habitacio" />
                    <img onClick={handleOnclik} name="green" src="images/green.svg" alt="apartament" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>)
}
export default Map
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

#map {
  display: block;
}

.normalscreen {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  left: 49%;
  position: relative;
}

.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

APP

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import Map from './Map'

function App() {

  return (<>
    <Navbar />
    <Map />
  </>);
}
export default withRouter(App)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding you want to change all images with .visible class attribute to hidden at the same time? If so, change the line `let pink = document.querySelector('.visible')` to `let pink = document.querySelectorAll('.visible')` to get all elements with this class name.

Then in your else statement you can loop over the results:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < pink.length; i++) {
   pink[i].classList.remove('visible')
    pink[i].classList.add('hidden')
}
```

The if statement `if (!pink)` may also need to be changed to `if(pink.length === 0)`

Comment: Yes I want to changel all the circleMarker with class attribute.
If I make all your changes and I click I have an error : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined**  /   **pink[i].classList.remove('visible')**
I I left  `let pink = document.querySelector('.visible')` and I put `for (var = i ....) {pink[i]....}` when I click I can see all the circleMarkers but when I click again nothing happens, the circleMarker don't hide

Comment: Answer updated, I think the if statement may also need to be changed. let me know if that works.